# WordPress | Set subscription renewal date after payment

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I want to set the renewal date of a subscription after the subscription has been placed.
Since I can code this myself I don't know where to put or how to listen to the actual event.

Is there something like an event in WordPress I can listen to?
Does someone have an example code?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You should probably check the [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-subscriptions/) for woocommerce subscription extension to see if you can find something there. And if you get stuck with that, then you should add what you tried here. This would help solve this for you.

Comment: Thank you for the hint dear shivaramanaiyer. I'm more interested in an example how I can listen to an subscription placed event or subscription payment event or something equivalent. Does this exist?